# Bigtable increasing rate of reading rows

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I'm doing an experiment to test Bigtable's capabilities compared to using Postgres.

I've set up a table with 50000 rows and 500 columns
I am trying to read all of those data back using the following code

```
# Create the Row Keys
row_set = RowSet()
start_key = f"tu7#s777#raw#"
end_key = f"tu7#s777#raw$"
row_set.add_row_range_from_keys(
    start_key=start_key.encode('utf-8'),
    end_key=end_key.encode('utf-8'))

# Read the Rows
rows = table.read_rows(row_set=row_set)
payload = {}
t = time.time()
for idx, row in enumerate(rows):
    pass
    
print(time.time() - t)
```

The output is that the query took about 4 to 5 minutes

[image: Performance]

The rate of reads for rows was around 200-600 rows per second

I am wondering, because Bigtable documentation says it supports up to "up to 10,000 rows per second reads" and up to "220 MB/s for scans", is there a way to increase my read rate. I am running my test by reading the data from a python script living on a jupyter notebook on a n1 standard 1 machine. Was the low read rate due to the processor? Or network throughput or other factors?

Comment: Are you sure that you using SSD? Have you tried without `enumerate`? Have you seen this document https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance?  there is a lot of information in this topic...

Comment: Yea I'm sure im using SSD

Comment: Tried removing enumerate, makes no difference

Comment: I do not have playground to test it, but if this is reproducable I suggest to raise a bug for it on https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/support/getting-support#issuetracker

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce number of columns. Having 500 in a row likely exceeds 1KB per row the estimate 10k/s was based on, https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance.

Instead of

key1 col1 col2

try

key1-col1 col1

key1-col2 col2